# Url con parametros no funciona en MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, mvc

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en mvc ha estado funcionando todo bien, pero no he podido solucionar un error, intento acceder a un url que cree desde global asax con parametros pero me manda error 404

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Unit",
            "Home/Unit/{id}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Unit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

aqui creo la ruta en jquery, añado la ruta a un div con texto

```
 $('#nombreUnidad').append("<a href='Unit/" + param.Unidad.Id + "/" + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "'>Nombre: " + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "</a>");
```

asi esta mi actionresult de mi controlador

```
 public ActionResult Unit(int id, string name)
    {

        return View("~/Views/Home/Unit.cshtml");
    }
```

las otras rutas que solo debuelven vistas y no tienen parametros si funcionan

Comment: ¿Que versión de MVC estas trabajando?

Comment: MVC 5 pero trabaje anteriormente con MVC 3 y del 5 casi no conozco

Answer (score 0):

En MVC 5 para retornar una vista, no es necesario cargarle la ruta cuando el controlador tiene el mismo nombre de la vista/parcial.

```
public ActionResult Unit(int id, string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Ahora, sí en tu vista tienes definido algun modelo o variable, ahí si tendras que asignarselo al view();

```
public ActionResult Unit(int id, string name)
{
    var model= bd.where(w => w.id == id && w.name == name)
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: muy bien, pero tengo la duda, quiero llegar a esa vista dandole click a un div, si, en este caso la vista tendra un modelo, es algo como perfiles, es por eso que en jquery creaba la ruta sobre el texto de un div para poder retornar la vista con los datos del unit que eleji

Answer (score 0):

Prueba colocando la ruta completa en el div, así:

```
 $('#nombreUnidad').append("<a href='http://localhost:puerto/Unit/" + param.Unidad.Id + "/" + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "'>Nombre: " + param.Unidad.NombreUnidad + "</a>");
```

Puedes probar también hacer un request a la acción con fiddler o postman y colocas un breakpoint en la acción para verificar que si hace el llamado al controlador.